# How can I change color of checkBox in qt with using python?

Tags: python, qt, qcheckbox, qpalette

I tried snipped code but somehow it didnt work for me. Any suggestions?

```
      checkBox.setPalette(QtGui.QPalette(QtGui.QColor(255,0,0)))
```

Comment: Can you give some more info as just this line? For example what is it for an object? How did you defined it and so on ...

Comment: checkBox is QtGui.QCheckBox()